# Get URL and access a running service without Minikube Cluster , using a Docker Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I'm running my Kubernetes Cluster using Docker and not using Minikube Cluster (requires a lot of memory) however after applying the required files, I can't get an external URL (like I used to have when I used Minikube) to run it in my Chrome browser.

Consider the followings:

The Pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: webapp-release-0-5
  labels:
    app: webapp
    release: "0-5"
spec:
  containers:
  - name: webapp
    image: richardchesterwood/k8s-fleetman-webapp-angular:release0-5
```

And its Service :

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fleetman-webapp

spec:
  # This defines which pods are going to be represented by this Service
  # The service becomes a network endpoint for either other services
  # or maybe external users to connect to (eg browser)
  selector:
    app: webapp
    release: "0-5"

  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30080

  type: NodePort
```

After applying both from Command line (WINDOWS 10 CLI) :

```sh
>>> kubectl get services
fleetman-webapp        NodePort    10.96.227.189    <none>        80:30080/TCP        5m57s

>>> kubectl get po

webapp                                   1/1     Running   0          12m
webapp-release-0-5                       1/1     Running   0          12m
```

However, I don't have an external URL of this POD to put in my browser to check out the App, like I used to have in Minikube.

How can we generate such URL?

Comment: [I've had some trouble with this](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2445) in the past, and it doesn't look like that issue really had a satisfactory outcome.  Hints there include changing the service to LoadBalancer type, using the imperative `kubectl expose deployment` command, or using the pod-side port.  I tend to use [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io) for my local-Kubernetes needs and it's served me pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

It's particularly hard to make it work in a bespoke way. I would suggest to use [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io) which creates kubernetes nodes as docker container. You can access NodePort service via `http://<NODEIP>:<NODEPORT>`. To get `NODEIP` use `kubectl get nodes`